# How to blend UV seams HLSL

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I wanted to create a shader without texture tiling. And i created a simple shader which contains dividing the UV into blocks and rotating them. But i cannot figure out how to create a blend between the edges of the UV blocks...

Here is my code:

```
Shader "Custom/Blend_4_test"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _TileCount("Tile Count", Range(2.0, 100.0)) = 4
        _TileCountInside("Tile Count Inside", Range(1.0, 10.0)) = 1
        _RotateAngle("Rotate Angle", Float) = 45.0
        _RotateNoise("Rotate Noise", Float) = 20.0

        [Enum(Texture,0,Checker,1)] _ViewMode("View Mode", Int) = 1
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "../Libraries/Helper.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            half _TileCount;
            half _TileCountInside;
            half _RotateAngle;
            half _RotateNoise;
            half _Mitigation;

            int _ViewMode;

            half Hash21(half2 p) {
                p = frac(p*half2(123.34, 456.21));
                p += dot(p, p+45.32);
                return frac(p.x*p.y);
            }

            half2 getNoise(half2 uv) {
                half2 st = uv * max(_TileCount, 1);
                half2 ipos = floor(st);
                return rand2(ipos, _RotateNoise);
            }

            int getChecker(half2 uv) {
                half2 ipos = sin(uv * _TileCountInside * 6.2831);
                return ipos.x * ipos.y > 0.;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f_img i) : SV_Target
            {
                half2 noise = getNoise(i.uv);

                i.uv *= _TileCount;

                half2 uvRotationPivot = (half2)0.5;
                i.uv -= floor(i.uv);
                i.uv -= uvRotationPivot;
                i.uv = mul(rot(radians(_RotateAngle * Hash21(noise))), i.uv);
                i.uv += uvRotationPivot;

                return _ViewMode ? getChecker(i.uv) : tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv * _TileCountInside );
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ruT.png

Comment: Do you want to blend this exact tile texture, or some less contrast texture, like dirt, concrete?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov This texture is just a checker that I add to check the transition between edges.

I need a math example of how I can achieve a smooth transition between edges, e.g https://github.com/mmikk/hextile-demo

I have a sample code, but I don't understand where the blending happens in the hex2colTex function 
https://github.com/mmikk/hextile-demo/blob/main/hextile-demo/hextiling.h

Comment: The demo you've linked seems to just add noise on the uvs, with noise strength proportional to distance to the hex borders. The margin of this noise is pretty thick so the borders are barely distinguishable. However I think the biggest thing that prevents "tiling" here is hexagonal grid structure, which is "non-linear" enough, so that the eyes can't catch the repetitive pattern (although noized) straight away.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I see. I just finished implementing this demo for my Unity project. Therefore i can close this topic. But it would be great if someone could give an example of a linear transition between edges.